# Python: Can't copy pygame surface objects

Tags: python, class, copy

I have a class:

```
class personInfo:
    def __init__(self,name,age,height,hairColour,face):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height 
        self.hairColour = hairColour
        self.face = face
```

I have several images here that I load in using the pygame module.

```
yellowFace = pygame.image.load("happy.png")
blueFace = pygame.image.load("sad.png")
redFace = pygame.image.load("angry.png")
```

I created an array that holds instances of that class. Here I am populating it.

```
personArray = []
while len(array) != 10:
    personArray.append(personClass("John",32,6,"Blond",yellowFace))
```

I would like to store the actual variables of that class (name, age height,hairColour, etc) in a variable I will call "personStorage". However, I can't have that var be mutatable since I need to access that var's values and change them. Doing this can't change the values of any instances inside the personArray.  How would I do this?

EDIT: 
I also can't seem to be able to Copy this class because I get a type error that says:  "can't pickle pygame.surface objects" since I have a value of a surface object within that class.

Comment: Do you mean something like `personStorage = ("John", 32, 6, "Brown"); personClass(*personStorage)`?

Comment: It would be more like personStorage = personArray[2] which would give me the values of what that specific instance has so I can then change them.  For example I could do personStorage.name = "Rick" for example. The problem I have is that personArray[2]'s name var is changed to "Rick", instead of the default value of "John"

Comment: So you basically need a copy of the `personInfo` instance, not just a reference to it? Implement `personInfo.__copy__` as described by the `copy` module, then use `personStorage = copy.copy(personArray[2])`. (`deepcopy` might be necessary, depending on your circumstances.)

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I need.  Then I would like to change a particular instance in the array.  For example personArray[2] = personStorage.  Just as an example.

Comment: If you are going to assign the modified copy back to the same slot, why not just modify the original in-place? I'm just trying to be clear about what it is you actually *need*.

Comment: In the future the values in the class will hold various images/surfaces.  In pygame I would to blit that image to the screen.  The Var personStorage needs to be a different image that the rest of the images in the overall array, which is why I need that variable personStorage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you're trying to do :

```
class PersonInfo:
    def __init__(self,name,age,height,hairColour):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height 
        self.hairColour = hairColour
    def toList(self):
        return [self.name, self.age, self.height, self.hairColour]
```

By the way, class names' first letter is always uppercase.

EDIT : To achieve what you're trying to do :

```
    old = PersonInfo("old", 1, 2, "blue")
    new = PersonInfo(*old.toList())
    new.name = "new"
    print(old.name) #'old'
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant.  I meant creating an entirely new var that I could change, however, it's vars would be accessed from a particular instance in the class array.  For example, personStorage = personArray[2]. I want to change the values that personStorage has without changing the values of personArray.

Comment: OK ! I edited my answer so it matches what you're trying to do.

Comment: What if I have a pygame surface object value in that class? I edited the original question to match this problem. Because using this method I am getting a TypeError that says: "can't pickle pygame.Surface objects"

Answer (score 0):

I have created setters and getters to get the data.Also you can create a copy of the instance that holds the data.

```
from copy import deepcopy
class PersonInfo:
    def __init__(self,name,age,height,hairColour):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height 
        self.hairColour = hairColour

x = PersonInfo("Mario",34,1.70,"blue")

print(x.height)  # prints 1.70

x1 = deepcopy(x)

print(x1.age)
```

Comment: This is just verbose boilerplate that doesn't prevent the kind of inadvertent modifications the OP is concerned about.

Comment: @chepner fixed.

Comment: OK, now the getters and setters are just unnecessary boilerplate. Get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the copy module:

The function copy() shallow copy operation on arbitrary Python objects.

```
import copy


class PersonInfo:
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, hair_colour):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.hairColour = hair_colour


personArray = []
for x in range(20, 24):
    personArray.append(PersonInfo("John", x, 6, "Brown"))


personStorage = copy.copy(personArray[2])
personStorage.name = "Ana"

print("\rpersonArray[2].name is %s\n"
      "\rpersonStorage.name is %s"
      % (personArray[2].name, personStorage.name))
```